# How to pass custom data to a Partial View in ASP.NET Core using ViewDataDictionary

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I am trying to pass custom data to a Partial View using an instance of  ViewDataDictionary

In prior versions the following code worked

@Html.Partial("PartialName", new ViewDataDictionary { { "key", "value" }})

but not in ASP.NET Core.

I have read the documentation but I cannot figure out how to create a working example.

Answer (score 2):

I used the following code to create a ViewDataDictionary

```
new ViewDataDictionary(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.EmptyModelMetadataProvider(), new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelStateDictionary()) { { "key", "value" } }
```

Answer (score 0):

In .NET Core that is also possible but you have to use following syntax:

```
await Html.RenderPartialAsync("PARTIAL_VIEW_NAME")
```

As you can see bellow that method also has version with ViewDataDictionary parameter:
[image: RenderPartialAsync]

Also be sure that you Partial View has proper model defined!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Sorry if I was not clear in my question but my problem is in the ViewDataDictionary creation syntax.

Comment: Something like that is working fine for me: "new ViewDataDictionary { {"x", "y"} }"

Comment: This code gives the following syntax error: 'ViewDataDictionary' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments

Comment: I am getting exactly the same error message when rewriting an existing website using VS2015. My code worked OK in VS2010. Have you managed to find a way to successfully display your data?